# Android not executable: 64-bit ELF file

Tags: android, c

I'm trying to build a C binary for my Oneplus 3T (LogoInjector) which uses a snapdragon 821 so it's a arm64 device.

When I run:

```
android-ndk-r13b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc -I android-ndk-r13b/platforms/android-24/arch-arm64/usr/include -c LogoInjector.v1.4.c lodepng
```

and copy the compiled binary to /system/bin on my phone I get this error:

```
sush: /system/bin/LogoInjector: not executable: 64-bit ELF file
```

I also tried the 32 bit toolchain but then it gives me:

```
sush: /system/bin/LogoInjector: not executable: 32-bit ELF file
```

I set the binary's permission to 755 just like all the others in /system/bin

Can anyone help me fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `-c` switch is instructing the compiler to perform the compilation only step, skipping the linkage stage, producing an object file and not executable. Invoke the

```
aarch64-linux-android-gcc -I android-ndk-r13b/platforms/android-24/arch-arm64/usr/include LogoInjector.v1.4.c -o lodepng
```

command instead. It is possible that you will need to specify some linker options (like libraries to link with) in addition to these parameters.

Answer (score -1):

I met this issue when trying to run an application. 
Try to run command :"file nameapp". Here I get:

> ELF executable, 32-bit LSB arm, dynamic (/system/bin/linker), not stripped.

But my board run command:"file system/bin/sh"

> ELF shared object, 64-bit LSB x86-64, dynamic(/system/bin/linker64), for Android 27,BuildID=4a49062467e2958e78ce79839f483302, stripped.

It's different so cannot run.
If you want to run it. Get the file with x86-64.

Comment: This is not related to the question problem actually